# function calls in template arguments

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm struggling with the following situation.

```
#include "systemc.h"

template<int maxval>
class Foo {
  /* Error: calls to constructors and functions cannot be part of a constant expression */
  sc_uint<int(log2(double(maxval)))> a;
  ...
};

int main() {

  Foo<10> foo;
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

As you can observe above, the templated class 'Foo' has the template parameter 'maxval'. 'Foo' also holds a member, again a templated class, that uses the template parameter 'maxval' together with the function 'log2' in its template arguments for instantiation.
However, the depicted code will not work since e.g. function calls cannot be part of constant expressions.
Do you see any possibility to evaluate e.g. log2(maxval) during compile time and to use the result for further template arguments inside 'Foo'?

Thanks for your help.
(I'm using GCC 4.1.2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Templates expect compile-time values. The `log2` function would need to be `constexpr` for this to work (which it isn't).

You'd have to define your own `constexpr` function. In the case of a logarithm function to the base 2 it can work if you need an integer (cutting off the floating point part):

```
constexpr int log2(int number, int acc = 0) {
    return number <= 1 ? acc : log2(number / 2, acc + 1);
}
```

**Edit:**

I did not notice that the question asked for GCC 4.1, which does not support `constexpr`. While you should try to upgrade if that option is available to you, you can also go for a template-based solution, as proposed in @Florian's answer.

**Edit 2:**

In case you do not want to rely on *Boost*, here is a simple template-based implementation you could use:

```
template<int V>
struct log2 {
    static int const value = 1 + log2<V/2>::value;
};

template<>
struct log2<0> {};

template<>
struct log2<1> {
    static int const value = 0;
};
```

Then you'd use it as `log2<13>::value`, which would result in `3`.

**Yet another edit:**

The `constexpr` implementation above will return `0` for `0` and negative numbers, which is a mistake. The logarithm is not defined for zero or negative values (in the real domain), so the function can be adjusted to throw an error (since it's getting a bit unreadable, I added some line breaks for formatting):

```
constexpr int log2(int number, int acc = 0) {
    return number <= 0
        ? throw std::logic_error{"Logarithm of zero or negative number not allowed."}
        : number == 1
            ? acc
            : log2(number / 2, acc + 1);
}
```

Comment: GCC 4.1 is way older than constexpr support.

Comment: Good point, sorry, didn't notice that. You'd either need to update your compiler (which you should definitely do, if you have the option, because 4.1 is very old and does not support many new features), or use @Florian's solution. I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @ Stjepan: Thanks a lot for your proposals! I think I have to go with the template-based solution since 'constexpr' does not work out for me, even with GCC5.2.0

Comment: @chessat2002 You need to compile with `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` to get `constexpr` support in GCC.

Comment: @ Holt: Perfect! Now, both solutions work, amazing help guys :)

Comment: Make the arguments unsigned (The second solution will not terminate using a negative value)

Comment: I had it `unsigned` originally, but I changed it to `int` only to match @chessat2002 's original code, where he also uses `int` as the parameter type. `unsigned` would probably be the semantically sound thing to do, although it's not a problem with the current implementation. `log2<x>::value` for negative values of `x` would keep integrally dividing by 2 until it reaches 0, and `log2<0>` does not have a value member, i.e. you'd be getting a compiler error.